# Html5 IndexedDB - retrieve a value by its key

Tags: html, indexeddb

In most turorials it is shown how to retrieve all the records from an object store by iterating over them with a cursor.
But how do you retrieve a value from an object store by its key "myKey" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for simple key/value storage then you might want to consider [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage). It's much more straightforward than using IndexedDB. It only works with strings (so far) but objects are easily stringified via the JSON object.

```
console.log( 'BEFORE', localStorage.getItem( 'test-key' ) );
localStorage.setItem( 'test-key', JSON.stringify( { 'foo': Math.round( Math.random() * 1000 ) } ) );
console.log( 'AFTER', JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'test-key' ) ) );
```

That said, you don't need a cursor to get a single value from a key in IndexedDB, only if you need to get multiple values for a key or range of keys. To get a value from a key, you do one of two things:

1) If `myKey` is your primary key (added when creating the store):

```
var request = transaction.get( key );
```

You can then add an `onsuccess` and `onerror` callback to parse the resulting event object, from which you'll want to extract the `event.target.result` value.

2) If `myKey` is in a non-primary index (one you've added after creating the store), you open the index on your transaction and then open the cursor on the index.

```
var transaction_index = transaction.index( index );
var request = transaction_index.get( key );
```

As for cursors (which you likely see discussed more often because you'll need one whenever you have multiple values stored under the same key), you can use those to retrieve values for a single key as well. Says [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#range-concept):

> A key range may consist of a single value.

You'll need to generate a `keyRange` using the `IDBKeyRange` object. Here's the helper method for that from [MIT-licensed InDB](http://github.com/editor/InDB) (my work-in-progress IndexedDB wrapper), which handles opening a cursor on a single value (e.g. `InDB.range.get( value )`) or a key range.

```
InDB.range.get = function ( value, left_bound, right_bound, includes_left_bound, includes_right_bound ) {
        if ( InDB.exists( left_bound ) && InDB.exists( right_bound ) && InDB.exists( includes_left_bound ) && InDB.exists( includes_right_bound ) ) {   
            return IDBKeyRange.bound( left_bound, right_bound, includes_left_bound, includes_right_bound ); 
        } else if ( InDB.exists( left_bound ) && InDB.exists( includes_left_bound ) ) {
            return IDBKeyRange.lowerBound( left_bound, includes_left_bound );
        } else if ( InDB.exists( right_bound ) && InDB.exists( includes_right_bound ) ) {
            return IDBKeyRange.upperBound( right_bound, includes_right_bound );
        } else if ( InDB.exists( value ) ) {
            return IDBKeyRange.only( value );
        }  else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Once you have the `keyRange`, you do one of two things:

1) If `myKey` is your primary key (added when creating the store), you open up a regular cursor on your transaction (with an optional direction).

```
var request = transaction.openCursor( keyRange, direction );
```

2) If `myKey` is in a non-primary index (one you've added after creating the store), you open the index on your transaction and then open the cursor on the index.

```
var transaction_index = transaction.index( index );
var request = transaction_index.openCursor( keyRange, direction );
```

Comment: it seems that "var request = transaction.get( key );" generates an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<IDBTransaction> has no method 'get'". I think I need to call .get() method on the objectStore and not the transaction as you have written. Is that right ?

Comment: You can only access object store data via the transaction, but you're correct that you call `get()` on `objectStore`. The var declaration for `transaction` isn't shown here but it would be something like `event.objectStore( database )`.

Comment: Worth noting, you open the transaction on the database (http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#idl-def-IDBDatabase) a la `var event = database.transaction( [ database ], type, timeout );`

Comment: "It's much more straightforward than using IndexedDB" except when you're working with Web Workers or Service Workers: you can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

There are some library that can help you using IndexedDB like [Dexie](https://dexie.org/), [JsStore](http://jsstore.net/), [LocalForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage), and [SFDatabase-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdatabase-js).

For me, it's easier with [SFDatabase-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdatabase-js) because the usage is almost similar with the [PHP version](https://github.com/ScarletsFiction/Scarlets/wiki/Database) when using MySQL/Redis as database. It also working for NodeJS.
All you need is define the database indexes structure and initialize the database.

```js
var myDB = new SFDatabase('myDB', {
    websql:false,
    idbVersion:1,
    databaseStructure:{
        Users:{
            // rowid -> always unique and incremental
            name:['text', 'unique']
        }
    }
}, function(){
    // database initialized
});
```

And after that, you can store almost anything in the database.

```js
myDB.insert('Users', {name:"Alex", age:17});
myDB.insert('Users', {name:"Ander", age:12});
myDB.insert('Users', {name:"Bell", age:30, admin:true});
```

If you like to obtaining single row data you can use `get`.

```js
myDB.get('Users', 'age', {name:"Ander"}, console.log);
//-> 12

myDB.get('Users', ['name', 'age'], {admin:true}, console.log);
//-> {name:"Bell", age:30}
```

And also obtaining multi row data.

```js
// Age more than 15
myDB.select('Users', ['name'], {'age[>]':15}, console.log);
//-> [{name: "Alex"}, {name: "Bell"}]

// Any name with 'e' and without 'A', and limit to two result
myDB.select('Users', ['name'], {'name[~]':'e', 'name[!~]'=>'A', LIMIT:2}, console.log);
//-> [{name: "Bell"}]
```